# How to set Magento price slider width mannually

Tags: javascript, css

I have a price slider in my project. It is working fine. But due to 100% width of the slider as per its container width, it doesn't look good. I don't know how to change width of the slider.

Comment: Can you share website link OR a demo link, where I can check this slider ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set max-width for the price slider but align it by center of the div using margin:0 auto;
display:block;
or
text-align:center